# How can I enable the default Start Menu in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, start-menu

The default Windows XP Start Menu has been disabled by the system administrator where I work. When you right-click on the Start Menu, and select Properties, the only option is the Classic Start Menu. I work in IT and have the complete freedom to change whatever I want, I just don't know how.

How do I enable to option to select the default Start Menu in XP?

The first option is completely gone. I only have the Classic Start Menu option available:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this Microsoft Knowledge Base article: [Policy settings for the Start menu in Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292504)

The first item in the list is `Disables the new simple Start menu and forces the classic 
Start menu.`  Hopefully you can just uncheck that, then enable the new-style Start menu the regular way.

Answer (score 0):

If you have complete freedom to change things then can you not ask to be excluded from the group policy which is enforcing the setting?